# Sequelize -- Use options.distinct with a Where Clause?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use Sequelize to find all distinct fields in a column, using a query with a `where` clause. I've searched the Sequelize docs and tried a number of different things, but haven't yet found the correct syntax.

Here's my current draft syntax:

```
var searchResults = connectors.cars.findAll({
    attributes: [
        connectors.Sequelize.options.distinct
    ],
    where: {
        condition: connectors.Sequelize.where(connectors.Sequelize.fn('LOWER', connectors.Sequelize.col('mfgr')), 'LIKE', '%' + searchString + '%')
     }
});
```

What is the correct way to use `options.distinct` alongside a `where` clause?

*Note:* edited to remove a bunch of extra code that had been requested in the comments, but which in retrospect may have been obfuscating the issue.

Comment: The code that you posted does not contain `indexOf`. Please provide the full code and/or stacktrace.

Comment: @alfasin, I've updated the post with the info requested.

Comment: Does the column `mfgr` contain `null`s? if yes, make sure your query filters them out before trying to apply `lower()` on its content.

Comment: @alfasin, the column `mfgr` does not contain `null`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the impression that this is hard to do in raw sql, let alone Sequelize. I found [an answer that uses raw sql here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/890598/SELECT-DISTINCT-on-one-column-with-multiple-column):

```
const myQuery = "WITH cte AS\n" +
    "(   SELECT id, mfgr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mfgr ORDER BY mfgr DESC) AS rn\n" +
    "    FROM cars\n" +
    "    WHERE LOWER(mfgr) like '%" + searchString + "%'\n" +
    ")\n" +
    "SELECT *\n" +
    "FROM cte\n" +
    "WHERE rn = 1";

let searchResults = connectors.db.query(myQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Really more of a comment, but what's going on with this code?

```
}).then((searchResults) => searchResults.map((item) => item.dataValues));
debugger;
return searchResults; <== ERROR IS THROWN HERE
```

1) What is the destination of the map()?  2) Won't the return occur *before* the results are returned, as it's not in the .then() block?  Should it not be more like this:

```
}).then((searchResults) => {
  var new_results = searchResults.map((item) => item.dataValues));
  debugger;
  return new_results;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `searchResults` returns a promise, which is resolved by the time it gets to the `.then` block marked `CODE EXECUTION NEVER GETS HERE`.  It works perfectly when I do the query as `var searchResults = connectors.cars.findAll({
 where: {
  condition: connectors.Sequelize.where(connectors.Sequelize.fn('LOWER', connectors.Sequelize.col('mfgr')), 'LIKE', '%' + searchString + '%')
 }
}).then((searchResults) => searchResults.map((item) => item.dataValues));`